# Erro ao tentar minificar arquivos js no grunt

Tags: grunt, ofuscação

Quando executo o comando *grunt uglify* aparece esse erro.

```
Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Warning: Task "uglify" not found. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

> Arquivo *gruntfile.js*

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
        dist: {
          files: {
            'dist/main.min.js': ["js/*.js"]
          }
        }
    },
    cssmin : {//task
        dist : {//targ
            files : {//configurações
                "dist/css/style.min.css" : ["css/*.css"]
            }
        }
    },
    watch : {
        dist : {//targ
            files : ["css/*.css"]
            tasks : ["cssmin"]
        }
    }
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-uglify");
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-cssmin");
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");  
}
```

Comment: Olá, como está o seu `package.json`?

Answer (score 1):

Esta faltando você registrar a tarefa do uglify, tente algo como:

`grunt.registerTask('u', ['uglify']);`

Então no cmd digite `grunt u`

Answer (score 0):

Não vejo algo errado na configuração, e coloque do caminho e das pastas conforma sua aplicação, fiz um exemplo apenas com o `uglify`, pois me pareceu que é nele o erro, tente usar desta forma:

```
uglify: {
     options: {
        mangle: false
     },
     my_target: {
        files: [{
           expand: true,
           cwd: 'assets/_js',
           src: '**/*.js',
           dest: 'assets/js/',
           ext: '.min.js'
        }]
     }
  }
```